# Prove the following characterization for inverse semigroups

Tags: semigroups, inverse-semigroups

I'm trying to prove the following characterization for inverse semigroups:

Let $S$ be a regular semigroup. For each $a \in S$ define $A(a) = \{x \in S : a = axa \}.$
The semigroup $S$ is inverse if and only if, for each a $\in S$, $A(a)$ contains a least
element with respect  to the natural partial order. (For $a,b \in S$, we have $a\leq b$ if there exists an idempotent $e$ such that $a=eb $).

---

It's easy to see that if $S$ is inverse, then for each $ x \in A(a)$ 
 we have that $a^{-1}\leq x$ since

$$a^{-1}=a^{-1}aa^{-1}=a^{-1}(ax)(aa^{-1})=a^{-1}(aa^{-1})(ax)=(a^{-1}a)(a^{-1}a)x=(a^{-1}a)x,$$
and therefor $a^{-1} $ is the least element of $A(a).$

Reciprocally, it's also easy to see that if $A(a)$ has least element $m$ then
$mam$ must equal $m$, otherwise we would have that $mam=k, k \neq m$ and therefor $k\leq m$ which is absurd since $m$ is the least of $A(a)$. So we conclude that the least element of $A(a)$ is one of the inverses of $a$. Note that if we assume that  $n$ is an inverse of $a$ and $m=en$ and $m=nf$ then $$n=nan=naman=na(en)an=naen=nama(en)=na(nf)a(en)=nfaen=mam=m $$

Since $m$ is the least element of $A(a)$ we have that $m=en$ for some idempotent $e$. So we only need to prove that there is a $f$ such that $m=nf.$

For some reason I'm having a hard time finishing this. It should be easy though.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the natural partial order is defined for regular semigroups? It is only defined for inverse semigroups in [Tero Harju’s Lecture Notes on Semigroups](http://users.utu.fi/harju/lectnotes.htm). Looking at the proof, the part for antisymmetry only works if idempotents commute, and the part for transitivity only works if the idempotents form a subsemigroup.

Comment: I understand that concern since in Howie's Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory the natural partial order is also only defined on inverse semigroups.  Regardless, I assumed it is, since otherwise the question I was posed makes no sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambooripad_order

Comment: So for the correct definition of the natural partial order, the existence of $f$ is already part of the definition of the partial order.